# Python remove all lines which have common value in fields

Tags: python, duplicates

I have lines of data comprising of 4 fields

```
aaaa bbb1 cccc dddd  
aaaa bbb2 cccc dddd  
aaaa bbb3 cccc eeee  
aaaa bbb4 cccc ffff  
aaaa bbb5 cccc gggg  
aaaa bbb6 cccc dddd
```

Please bear with me.

The first and third field is always the same - but I don't need them, the 4th field can be the same or different. The thing is, I only want 2nd and 4th fields from lines which don't share the common field. For example like this from the above data

```
bbb3 eeee  
bbb4 ffff    
bbb5 gggg
```

Now I don't mean deduplication as that would leave one of the entries in. If the 4th field shares a value with another line, I don't want any line which ever had that value.

humblest apologies once again for asking what is probably simple.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
from collections import defaultdict

LINES = """\
aaaa bbb1 cccc dddd
aaaa bbb2 cccc dddd
aaaa bbb3 cccc eeee
aaaa bbb4 cccc ffff
aaaa bbb5 cccc gggg
aaaa bbb6 cccc dddd""".split('\n')

# Count how many lines each unique value of the fourth field appears in.
d_counts = defaultdict(int)
for line in LINES:
    a, b, c, d = line.split()
    d_counts[d] += 1

# Print only those lines with a unique value for the fourth field.
for line in LINES:
    a, b, c, d = line.split()
    if d_counts[d] == 1:
        print b, d

# Prints
# bbb3 eeee
# bbb4 ffff
# bbb5 gggg
```

Comment: That's about perfect. Many thanks. I now need to weave it into my script, i'm iterating over a file, then making the output available in the script (via a dictionary) later on. Do you forsee any problems?

Comment: The only thing you need to be careful of is that I'm iterating over the lines twice - you can't simply replace my two "for line in LINES:" loops with two "for line in my_open_file:" loops, because the first loop will read the whole file and the second will have nothing to read.  Either store the lines in a list for the second loop to use, or seek() back to the start of the file before the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

For your amplified requirement, you can avoid reading the file twice or saving it in a list:

```
LINES = """\
aaaa bbb1 cccc dddd
aaaa bbb2 cccc dddd
aaaa bbb3 cccc eeee
aaaa bbb4 cccc ffff
aaaa bbb5 cccc gggg
aaaa bbb6 cccc dddd""".split('\n')

import collections
adict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in LINES: # or file ...
    a, b, c, d = line.split()
    adict[d].append(b)

map_b_to_d = dict((blist[0], d) for d, blist in adict.items() if len(blist) == 1)
print(map_b_to_d)

# alternative; saves some memory

xdict = {}
duplicated = object()
for line in LINES: # or file ...
    a, b, c, d = line.split()
    xdict[d] = duplicated if d in xdict else b

map_b_to_d2 = dict((b, d) for d, b in xdict.items() if b is not duplicated)
print(map_b_to_d2)
```